# i'm building app with eclipse i want create pdf diagrammatically

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using eclipse juno IDE.
I am facing the following error

> could not find class com.itextpdf.document

I'm using **itextg 5.5.8** library 
and also give permission in manifest file.

```
public void createPDF(View view){
        //reference to EditText
        EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_input);
        //create document object
        Document doc=new Document();
        //output file path
        String outpath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/mypdf.pdf";
        try {
        //create pdf writer instance
        PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(outpath));
        //open the document for writing
        doc.open();
        //add paragraph to the document
        doc.add(new Paragraph(et.getText().toString()));
        //close the document
        doc.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please guide.